# Url validation regex javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working on a URL validation using Javascript. Here I tried a regex that satisfies all my needs except one. I want to get the result `false` when the input is other than ".com". In the current situation it shows `true` for ".comm".

```js
var a=["https://www.example.com","https://www.example.com/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share","https://www.example.commmmm/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share"];
var re=/^((https):\/\/)?(www.)[a-z0-9]+(\.(com))+(.*)?$/;
a.map(x=>console.log(x+" => "+re.test(x)));
```

Comment: https://urlregex.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this by specifying that right after `com`, there can be anything starting with a slash or question mark (as it is also a valid case). Moreover, I think you should also add `-` to the part where you match the domain name as it is also a valid character in the domain names.

Here I have created a snippet with more test cases:

```js
var a=["https://www.ex-ample.com", "https://www.example.com", "https://www.example.com?ala=makota","https://www.example.com/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share","https://www.example.commmmm/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share"];
var re=/^((https):\/\/)?(www.)[a-z0-9-]+(\.(com))+(\/.*|\?.*)?$/;
a.forEach(x=>console.log(x+" => "+re.test(x)));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by insisting anything after the `.com` start with a slash. This can be done by inserting the slash in the `(.*)?` part like this `(\/.*)?` as in the snippet below. This says "after the .com there can be either nothing or anything starting with a slash". Note that the slash needs to be escaped with a backslash.

```js
var a=["https://www.example.com","https://www.example.com/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share","https://www.example.commmmm/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share"];
var re=/^((https):\/\/)?(www.)[a-z0-9]+(\.(com))+(\/.*)?$/;
a.map(x=>console.log(x+" => "+re.test(x)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood the question correctly.

Try the following regex pattern:

```py
var re=/^((https):\/\/)?(www.)[a-z0-9]+(\.(com))+(\/.*)?$/;
```

```js
var a=["https://www.example.com","https://www.example.com/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share","https://www.example.commmmm/hz/wishlist/ls/3LIMPQXAM4REU?ref_=wl_share"];
var re=/^((https):\/\/)?(www.)[a-z0-9]+(\.(com))+(\/.*)?$/;
a.map(x=>console.log(x+" => "+re.test(x)));
```

I checked your test cases and they are working fine.